# Does Ubuntu have website that I can see about change set like Fedora?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-wiki, changelog

I used Fedora before, and I always visit this https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases/36/ChangeSet to see if any change will come in next release. In Ubuntu, does it have something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For past and current release of Ubuntu**: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Look for the "Release Notes" link for the release that you are interested in.

For example, if you look at Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish Indri), you will see a Release Notes link that leads you to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ImpishIndri/ReleaseNotes

**For future releases of Ubuntu** there is no pre-written ironclad plan. Ubuntu depends upon upstream projects and volunteers, both of which are outside our control. Each Ubuntu team keeps an internal list the tasks they would like to accomplish...but that's not a guarantee to you that the work will be completed by release date. To view a team's wishlist, you generally must ask that team. Most of the discussion about wishlists and tasks takes place in the team's IRC channel, mailing list, or at discourse.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Given that the original question mentioned "changes in the next release", I'll mention here that right now the release notes for the future version 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish) still lead to a non-existing wiki page.

Comment: The example is **Fedora 36** that is "next" at this time.

Comment: Oh. Big edit to address.